# Can they make a digital copy of Lance Reddick for the "Continental" TV series?

Tags: john-wick, legal, the-continental

Lance Reddick has died, but they plan to make a TV show about [*The Continental*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Continental_(miniseries)). Is it possible to "revive" dead actors through some digital technology? Is this primarily a legal question - who gets the money from the acting - the family of Lance?

Comment: Doing it via CGI? Yes. Legal? ... (ask a lawyer?) I think that it's not really something we can tell you (as for the second part).

Comment: They're not gonna do that, it will be way too costly.

Comment: They have made CGI appearances of many actors/actresses who left us but they were mostly been short appearances as cost do matters.

Comment: As others have said, feasible? Yes, will they? You will have to wait and see, but given the logistics of filming, probably not.

Comment: On a level of ironic/coincidental sadness, I'm right in the middle of re-watching the Wire, top to bottom, first time in maybe 15 years. It's odd to know some are no longer with us, & balance that against who was in it that I'd never even heard of at the time, now familiar faces. I really never knew Littlefinger was in it until now. Driss & Dominic West I did figure out years ago, but not the first time.

Comment: Not being a big *John Wick* fan, I read this and was imagining a show with Lance Reddick as [The Continental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Continental_(Saturday_Night_Live))...

Comment: They're already doing this with Bruce Willis. He sold his "digital rights". Possible? Yes. Legal? Yes... but someone has to get permission to do this. Likely in the future as "deepfake" technology gets better, this will become more and more popular, even with living and fully capable actors (why work for 6 weeks when they can just "generate" your work for you?).

Comment: They did it in 1993 with Brandon Lee for "The Crow", so it's definitely possible, but the legal issues are a completely different topic. https://www.looper.com/253529/heres-how-they-finished-the-crow-after-brandon-lee-died-during-filming/

Comment: Continental is gonna be a **prequel** with a new cast, in particular Ayomide Adegun as Charon. So... while perhaps they could "bring him back", they **won't**.

Answer (score 14):

Can it be done?
Yes.
It would be much easier if he had recently posed for a photogrammetry, 3D scanning session…
This takes under 30 seconds to do, with >200 individual stills cameras, but idk how long to them map to a useable form. I've been in these booths myself, many times, but I've never seen the process to completion, after this part.

[image]

…but it has been done just from existing footage of an actor in a previous movie & a plaster head cast made some years earlier, for another movie - viz Peter Cushing in Star Wars.

[image]

Will they do it? Your guess is as good as anyone else's.
It's expensive. It requires a mo-cap actor to convincingly portray him. It then has to have the 3D model mapped onto that.
It *then* needs a voice actor who can sound convincingly like him.
More background to this on [Star Wars Fandom](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Cushing)

As to the rest - there's the moral issue, for which his estate would have to make the decision. Recompense would presumably go to his estate, but all that would be guided by a room-full of lawyers.

Comment: One could argue that the voice impersonation alone is infeasible— Reddick had a very distinctive voice and I’m not sure if it could be imitated convincingly, even with an AI assist

Comment: There is enough of a push, and a desire, in this area for it to not be infeasible for much longer.

Comment: I recall that the plaster cast of Cushing's face was not made for Star Wars, but for the 1984 spy spoof *Top Secret!*, and solely for a gag where he's first seen looking at something through a magnifying glass, and then moves the lens away and his eye is actually shaped like that.

Comment: @KevinTroy have you listened to any recent ElevenLabs generated voices? They are quite quickly getting scarily good, especially in non-realtime cases where you can generate many "takes" and pick the best ones. They also require very little training data

Comment: @blobbymcblobby at least, finally they can stop wasting all their money on talented actors and give it to the CEO and shareholders where it truly belongs

Answer (score 6):

Just adding a cent to what Tetsujin has said:

And, largely what he has described is traditionally done in post production.

But what if all of that was done before, prepped, and then applied to a body/head double, that then proceeded to act on set as if they were them, all the time the projected face is already mapped on to them and seen by the camera recording? No need for lengthy and costly post production.

Feasible? Yes.

With the scanning he has mentioned, I too have done it, I have also been on the other side ..

With enough of the correct information they can do it in real time.

I have been on sets where they did this in real time, and even the stand-ins were projected with the talents features and all you needed was the voice (which can also be done). At the very least, you could shoot it as normal, without requiring post production.

But would they?

Legal/Estate/etc issues aside, the technology required for this in real time filming requires a few extra bits of equipment and brain cells, and throws in a few extra requirements, so it is not 'easy', but it is do-able.

That said, its a lot easier to film scenes without that extra baggage, and it is not insignificant, so for my money, they would probably recast and get on with it.

Particularly as legal/estate/etc issues are avoided by recasting.

I was having a chat this very recently about some such, including adding the voice to the face, and Val Kilmer's AI'd voice in Top Gun2 came up as an example. That was post-produced for that project, but real time is here already.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen tech demos of this live compositing right 'in camera' - it didn't occur to me to include it. Thanks for adding.

Comment: @Tetsujin  It was pretty cool to be part of it! I was at the Cinematographers Convention recently and I don't think they even had it there (but everything else was). But, Oh boy, did I feel old. Totally surrounded by what looked like teens discussing where they are in their shoot schedule... :/

Comment: Ah, also reminds me of that social media app where the makeup is applied in real time, on any face and is quite convincing (as social media levels of quality goes).

Comment: mhm, we've already got 'social media' levels of functional already - Zoom-type apps with 'face of a dog/monkey/boy/girl'. I suppose you could do it if the actor was wearing a 'face cam' of some sort - but the breakthrough will be when they can pick them out of a crowd, live. I suppose the 'face-full of dots' might help for that, like they do for doubles. There was a funny moment in the last Bond, Daniel Craig next to two identical 80s Astons, chatting with both his doubles, same suit, same hair, two with faces full of dots. Great 'wtf' moment on a sunny day out in the middle of London.

Comment: @Tetsujin haha, reminds me of another shoot where the guy was covered in the black and white checkers and wore a huge thing on his head that he had trouble getting through doors (and then gets mostly cut from the movie..). As for picking out faces in the crowd, ask the Chinese! (haha, oops, cough). With the real time on set shooting, they didn't have to wear the dots - relevant features were already mapped out s/w side.

Comment: You've not seen anything until you've seen Dumbo's double. I kid you not. Short gymnast, dressed in green lycra of course, extended grey front legs, grey head & trunk with camera in it. He was brilliant, really got the characterisation, but it was hilarious to watch the setups.

Comment: :P I think what i meant with the social media bit was that the tracking had obviously improved over the usual dog ear type apps where the mapping was now pretty robust, and not so 'loose' as previously seen, and well blended to look relatively realistic (i'm no MUA).